# How low underground could you go?

Tags: science-based, underground, secret-society

How far underground, assuming we're talking about a secret underground "living area", could be hospitable for human life assuming you don't want to hit the mantle? Would there be a pressure difference, and if so, what equipment would be required at such a level? Would it be too hot or too cold down there?

Comment: AFAIK, deep coal mines are hot enough (e.g. > 40°C) to be not really "livable" areas

Comment: Food and breathable air would be major limitations.

Comment: This pretty much covers it.  https://what-if.xkcd.com/135/

Comment: Also.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys! Pretty much what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to escape from? If it's a Theia like collision you may as well not try.

Comment: Are you asking about Earth specifically?

Comment: You know there is about three times more water in the earth than in the oceans. And this was a recent discovery, in times where almost no-one questions that earth is almost entirely molten. The truth is, we really don't know what is inside ou planet. We just make guesses, then assume they're right until they're proven not to be. Just like the earth was definitely flat untill we found out it wasn't.

Comment: but the movement of earth quake waves does give good hints about what density whatever soup is inside the planet might have. Anyway - do you just need rock or ground above you in a specific quantity? If that is the case, just drill yourself inside the biggest mountain, and you have up to 8km of rock above you without the heat from below being a problem; as long as you do not try to drill a hole in an active volcano of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Heat based limit

The [TauTona Mine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TauTona_Mine) is the deepest mine on the Earth.  It is a gold mine.

Tip of the TauTona mine iceberg:
[image: TauTona Mine]

TauTona Mine:
[image: TauTona Mine]

#### Characteristics

- Depth - 2.4 miles
- Ambient Air Temperature - 55C (131 F)
- Rock Face Temperature - 60C (140 F)

If the air conditioning stops working, the ambient air temperature can kill the miners.  On average 5 miners die every year in this mine.

I assume that without active cooling, this is below the lowest inhabitable depth.

***Less than 2 miles of depth***

### Oxygen/Carbon Dioxide Based Limit

Underground there's very limited life able to convert our wastes ($CO_2$, urine, & feces) back into forms that we can use.  Although we have many mines located a mile or more below ground, all of these require air exchange to keep humans alive.

#### Active

Very deep & active mines require the use of active system to exchange air with the surface (e.g. fans & blowers) to keep the miners from suffocating.  If your blowers stopped working for more than an hour or so, expect your population to begin suffocating.

If you assume an active air handling system that never suffers failures, then keeping the air fresh is:

***Not a limiting factor***

#### Passive

It should be possible to create a passive air exchange system using the dynamic pressure of wind passing over special chimneys and other techniques to exchange air with the surface, this probably limits the depth of the mine too.

Without actually modeling such a system, I don't really know what the limit would be.  One unfortunate fact is that $CO_2$ gas is heavier than $O_2$, so it will tend to settle to the bottom of your hole.

If you assume a passive air handling system, then you're limited by the volume and forces such passive system can generate.  The exact answer will depend strongly upon the details of the configuration so I can't give you an exact answer.

***Unknown*, but I would guess less than 1 mile**

#### Closed Loop Life Support

If you built your secret place more like a permanent space colony which only needed the input of energy to keep it going, then this wouldn't be an issue.  However, it does point back to the first part of the answer in which you still need to find a heat sink to keep the place livable.

Getting energy isn't a problem, however, dumping your waste heat will become a problem at depth.  My guess is the limits of your ability to dump waste heat will require you to limit your maximum depth even more than the open-loop environmental systems would.

A closed-loop life support system would ensure that you would not need to place your secret hidey hole near the surface to maintain a supply of fresh air.

***My guess is 1 mile < your maximum depth < 2 miles***

Comment: Hot iceberg? Strange thing to call it. It's not 10% *above* ground either. So what's the reference?

Comment: "Hot iceberg" isn't in my answer.  Was this a comment for another question/answer?

Comment: Ah, I used the term "iceberg" as in "10% is visible while 90% is hidden".  Although with this mine that's a significant understatement.  Very little of the mine is visible from the surface - but even that little bit is damned impressive.

Answer (score 5):

### At least 11km

The main problem is going to be heat. Why not then use the largest naturally occurring source for cooling, the ocean?

The [Mariana Trench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariana_Trench) is almost 11 kilometres deep, making the surrounding rock stay cool, so if you burrow your base only a little further down than that, the temperature is not going to be a problem.

A pressure-resistant habitat can survive the pressure, as proven by the descent into the trench by [Jacques Piccard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Piccard) in 1960, or more recently by James Cameron in [Deapsee Challenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepsea_Challenger) in 2012.